# Why isn't underscore consistent with its type checking?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

For example it has `isNumber()` which uses toString which will detect both primitive numbers and "boxed" numbers.

But later in its code it will use typeof which will not detect boxed values.

I know that typeof is faster but it will miss boxed values.

This issue was brought up in my code base as well, and why I ask the question.  Something to the effect of "if you don't use your own functions why would someone else".

Is there something I'm missing here:

[Use of typeof](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L601)

```
if (typeof isSorted == 'number') {
```

[isNumber defenition](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L1137)

```
_.each(['Arguments', 'Function', 'String', 'Number', 'Date', 'RegExp'], function(name) {
    _['is' + name] = function(obj) {
      return toString.call(obj) === '[object ' + name + ']';
    };
  });
```

Comment: Underscore does not use `_.isNumber` at all (it only defines it), I'd call that pretty consistent. Boxed numbers are an antipattern.

Comment: "if you don't use your own functions why would someone else" was the core of my question.  It appears underscore consistently does not use `isNumber()`

Answer (score 1):

That line is part of a method which expects either a `boolean` or `number` as its third argument.

```
_.indexOf = function(array, item, isSorted) {
    if (array == null) return -1;
    var i = 0, length = array.length;
    if (isSorted) {
      if (typeof isSorted == 'number') {
        i = isSorted < 0 ? Math.max(0, length + isSorted) : isSorted;
      } else {
        i = _.sortedIndex(array, item);
        return array[i] === item ? i : -1;
      }
    }
    for (; i < length; i++) if (array[i] === item) return i;
    return -1;
  };
```

If you pass it something unexpected (like a boxed number) it will barf, and that's your problem, not theirs.